# Page reload after form submit using WFFM Sitecore8

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore8

I have created one form using WFFM, and a sending mail on tap of submit button, 
After click on submit button it display message "Thank you for filling in the form" and textbox is hidden after submission the form. and when I refresh website it ask me to repeat action.

How can I hide the form after submission?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `Success Mode` field to `Redirect` would certainly be a good workaround to your problem. A dedicated thank you page has the added benefit of being easier to goal track with 3rd party analytics tools like Google Analytics.

Comment: I have form in footer and it is displaying in all pages. What should I do to refresh current page because I can not specify specific page